# Does Debian have a Perl style guide?

Tags: debian, perl

I'm going to be writing some heavy patches for Debian perl utilities. I have a lot of experience doing this. Some of their methods are *really* antiquated, like [bareword file handles.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/perl/FIO00-PL.+Do+not+use+bareword+file+handles). Is there a style guide or something that Debian uses for their Perl code?

I don't see it in the [Debian Perl Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/perl-policy/)

Comment: You'd probably have better luck posting to the mailing lists.

Comment: I don't think there is a guide akin to what you are looking for. I think the guidelines/recommendations I linked to are all they may have. I agree with @muru -- try posting to the mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [Debian Perl Group Policy](https://pkg-perl.alioth.debian.org/policy.html). It contains all information on how the Debian Perl Group manages itself. Also, you can find some more information at the Debian Perl Group '[Welcome](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/DebianPerlGroup/Welcome)' page.

Edit: I don't think that the Debian Perl Group has a style guide. I may be wrong, but I am not aware of one. The content of the links I left are what I am familiar with.